# Create a condition in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have this piece of code:

```
cond=(gd_all_df['dateOfLastContact']> '2020-10-10') & (gd_all_df['dateOfLastContact']<pd.to_datetime('now').strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))

gd_all_df_test=gd_all_df_contact[cond]
```

I have a big data frame and I would like to work only with data from 2020-10-10
But I get this warning : `UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.`

And the condition `('Cond')in gd_all_df_test` is not applied

Comment: We don't know what type of data you are trying to compare. Please provide a sample data.

Comment: it s string data

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what format your ***dateOfLastContact*** column is.
First try getting it in proper format of date to compare by below method

```
gd_all_df['dateOfLastContact']=gd_all_df['dateOfLastContact'].apply(pd.to_datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

And then its better idea to have a variable for the date for comparison may be today as you have given the code snippet.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.now()
date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

cond = (gd_all_df[gd_all_df['dateOfLastContact']> '2020-10-10']) & (gd_all_df[gd_all_df['dateOfLastContact'] < date])
```

Let me know if you are still facing issue.